# How to group and color code data based on two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following Excel file: https://ufile.io/haq5p
How can I achieve effect in column C ? 
( Don't need to mark them like in A and B. Did that just to show that values in C relate to values in B )

[image: Excel threads]

Comment: How do they relate? Looks like conditional formatting based on a function would do what you need...

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

Comment: That might be so but I couldn't find the right formula. Basically a screw is grouped by it's diameter and gets a color based on a "Thread pitch".

Answer (score 0):

With Conditional Formatting a separate rule is required for each colour (when not applying a Color Scale) and the following should serve, having selected ColumnC, for the rules as indicated. I suspect there are more rules but if you can't be bothered to tell us what they are ....

Yellow: `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)="x0,5"`
Amber: `=OR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)="x0,75",C1=0.8)`
Red: `=C1=1`
Maroon: `=C1=1.25`

Output with CF for ColumnC:

[image]

Comment: I think the formula would need to create a scale by grouping all of the screws by the diameter and assign a place in that group based of the  thread pitch. Than to each place in a group can have a color. In case of your formula Screws with a "thread pitch" other than specified would not have a color assigned.